# How to forward host ports of < 1024 to a VirtualBox NAT-connected machine?

Tags: routing, virtualbox, nat, port-forwarding, kernel

The manual says: *"Forwarding host ports < 1024 impossible: On Unix-based hosts (e.g. Linux, Solaris, Mac OS X) it is not possible to bind to ports below 1024 from applications that are not run by root"*.

Is it possible to disable this limitation? I run main internet services (such as mail server, for example (SMTP, IMAP, LDAP, HTTP, HTTPS), as VBoxHeadless machines and capture host's ports by VBoxManage modifyvm --natpf1). The only solution I can see now is capturing a higher port and redirecting traffic meant for a lower port by means of iptables or redir. But maybe there is more natural solution?

Answer (score 5):

As clarified [in the VirtualBox documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html), that is a well known limitation of the NAT mode. You could do two different things.

1. Forward ports through NAT

   VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,80000,,80"
2. Switch to the "Bridged Networking" mode

Reading from the documentation:

> This is for more advanced networking
>   needs such as network simulations and
>   running servers in a guest. When
>   enabled, VirtualBox connects to one of
>   your installed network cards and
>   exchanges network packets directly,
>   circumventing your host operating
>   system's network stack.

Comment: I know of 2., but I prefer using things which I know how do they work and kip it simple. So, now I use 1. with redir to redirect host's 80 port to host's 80000 powrt, which is then captured by VirtualBox and taken to VM's 80.